# Getting id from sqlite raw and make it integer type

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello I develop register screen in android and  I need to get id from my database by entered username and password that stores database and make it as int.Firstly user will register then type name and pass and login up.In my database I have many raws like:id username password.I want to get id of entered username and password.For ex:id:1 username:A pass:a id:2, username:B pass:b.. and when user A entered his name and pass and login up i should get his id then make it int type if you dont  something please leave comment thanks
I tried to made attempt but i dont know is it rightand how to develop it:

```
EditText name;
 String Username = name.getText().toString();

Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +LOGIN_TABLE  + " where username = '"+Username+"'", null);
```

and in this code Login table is my table name?

Comment: Paste what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the built in id field of the database, I recommend changing the query a bit.

I find that if I did not define the _id row in my create table statement, I do not get it in Select * statements.

`Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +LOGIN_TABLE  + " where username = '"+Username+"'", null);`

Can be switched to:

`Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, * FROM " +LOGIN_TABLE  + " where username = '"+Username+"'", null);`

After that, when you get it from the cursor, use this to find the id:

`Long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));`

**EDIT:**

Before calling the last line of code here, make sure to move the cursor to the first result.

```
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
    id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
}
```

Comment: thanks but when i am entering username and password it tels that Long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id")); is not working -- android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 what it can be?

Comment: Check what <code>c.getColumnIndex("_id")</code> returns. If that is something that is not -1, then it would be that the result cursor was not moved to the first option in the cursor. Check the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much it works,but how did you know that its moveToFirst() method and not the moveToNext()? sorry for this question but I am newbie in android dev.  and I dont understand this methods well, would you mind to answer

Comment: moveToFirst takes the cursor and has it point to the first item in your cursor. If you were searching for something with multiple results, you would use moveToNext after the moveToFirst to move through all of the results.

Answer (score 1):

Get the id from database as:

```
String id = c.getString(1);//c is object of cursor
```

then convert to integer by using **Integer.parseInt()**

```
int integerId = Integer.parseInt(id);
```

Comment: String id = c.getString(1); this is get only id that equal =1?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addData(View view){
    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);
    //normally the id is comming as int , i changed it to string
    long val = dbHandler.addInfo(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

    if(val > 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inserting Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: this code thrown there is not a good way to answer a question, please provide some more details